# ZBar library build failed with Android NDK (expected identifier or '(' before '.')

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, qr-code, zbar

I can't build the ZBar C++(?) library with Android NDK and I haven't found anything that could help me understand when I've been searching the web for information about it. This is a bit outside of my area, so I hope someone might be kind enough to help me get this working.

Background: I've been trying to implement a simple QR scanner in my Android app without increasing the app size too much. I've looked at the Obsqr project (https://bitbucket.org/trikita/obsqr) which is a very small QR scanner, based on the ZBar library. I've successfully implemented a QR scanner with the ZBar library using the regular library (http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/), but that made my 3 MB apk twice the size, so ideally I'd like to found a way to solve it the same way as it's done in Qbsqr. It uses Android NDK to compile the C++ library as far as I can tell, though I've never worked with C++ or Android NDK before.

I've downloaded the code and tried to build the app myself before I try to modify it for my use, but I just can't get it to work. The ndk-build gives the following error message:

```
\src\main\jni\bch15_5.c:1:1 : expected identifier or '(' before '.' token
```

The file itself looks like this:

```
../../../zbar/zbar/qrcode/bch15_5.c
```

Since I haven't done any programming in C++, I'm not sure what it should look like, but from what I have seen when searching the web for help, the file doesn't look much like any other C++ file I've seen. Almost all of the files in the library seem to have the same structure, so I'm not sure what to do with them.

Does anybody know if I should change the files in any way or have I forgotten to do something before building the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project on bitbucket seems to be screwed up: it shows symbolic links instead of actual files. You should download https://bitbucket.org/trikita/zbar/ and follow the build instructions there.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Using those files instead, I managed to get it working.